# Python list - adding elements to the list

Tags: python

I am trying to add two elements to the list but only one of them gets listed but the previous one is not getting appended at all

```
choice = [[1, 2], [3, 5]]
c = 5
for loop in range(n):
    diff = choice[loop][1]-choice[loop][0]
    choice_variant = []
    print(diff)
    for item_c in range(c):
        if(item_c+1+diff>c):
            break
        si,ei = item_c+1,item_c+1+diff
        print([si,ei])
        choice_variant.append([si,ei])
```

Output is coming as below

```
 - 1
[1, 2]
[2, 3]
[3, 4]
[4, 5]
- 2
[1, 3]
[2, 4]
[3, 5]
```

when I try to iterate through the list - choice_variant , it shows me this `[[1, 3], [2, 4], [3, 5]]` which is the second set but misses the first set

```
 - 1
[1, 2]
[2, 3]
[3, 4]
[4, 5]
```

Comment: This code doesn't appear to compile

Comment: What is `choice`? What is `n`?

Comment: You're resetting `choice_variant` to the empty list on each iteration, so it makes a lot of sense that it only contains data from the last iteration

Comment: @ScottHunter- Value of n = 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

declare `choice_variant = []` outside of the for loop

EDIT:

sorry forgot the explain: declaring it inside of the for loop reinitializes the empty list for each iteration.

As for your comment: to get nested lists. Keep `choice_variant = []` where it is and initialize an outer list that will consist of the `choice_variant` lists. So you'll have:

```
result = []
c = 5
for loop in range(n):
    diff = choice[loop][1]-choice[loop][0]
    choice_variant = []
    print(diff)
    for item_c in range(c):
        if(item_c+1+diff>c):
            break
        si,ei = item_c+1,item_c+1+diff
        print([si,ei])
        choice_variant.append([si,ei])
    result.append(choice_variant)
```

Comment: I tried that but it is storing as  [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5], [1, 3], [2, 4], [3, 5]]
but i would want it as two blocks as n = 2 in my case.                                                             
 [ [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5]], [[1, 3], [2, 4], [3, 5]] ]

Comment: A good answer should also explain _why_. [Answer]

Comment: I got the expected results now. Thanks everyone

Comment: modified code                                                                                                
choice_variant = []
for loop in range(n):
    temp_list = []
    diff = choice[loop][1]-choice[loop][0]
    print(diff)
    for item_c in range(c):
        if(item_c+1+diff>c):
            break
        si,ei = item_c+1,item_c+1+diff
        print([si,ei])
        temp_list.append([si,ei])
    choice_variant.append(temp_list)